# Search through the data with a loop or nested loops in SAS

Tags: sas

I am rather a beginner in SAS. I have the following problem. Given is a big data set (my_time) which I imported into SAS looking as follows

[image]

I want to implement the following algorithm 
for every account look for a status and if it is equal to **na** then look for the same contract after one year (one year after it gets the status **na**) and put the information "my_date", "status" and "money" in three new columns "new_my_date", "new_status" and "new_money" like in

[image]

I need something like `countifs` in excel. I found loops in SAS like [DO](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat481/node/41)  but not for the purpose to look through all rows.
I do not even know for which key word I have to look.

I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: How do you decide it is _one year later_ : when `year` is advanced with at least 1 year or when `my_date` is advanced with at least 12 months? What if an account reappears 13, 14 and 15 months after it's status becomes 'na' : will you write out a line for each?

Comment: Is the dataset so big dat performance is an issue? If yes, it is important to know if the dataset is sorted upfront.

Comment: @DirkHorsten: one year later means my_date+12 month. that is the reason why I introduces my_date in my data. that is a data set where every account appears monthly wit a status. We want to check the status 12 month after the status ='na'

Comment: the data set is sorted the performance should not be an issue

Comment: HOW is it sorted. The snippet of data you gave is to small to see that

Answer (score 5):

A simple method would be by sorting, then exploiting the special variable prefix `first.` and `retain` statement to get the desired result.

**Step 1: Sort by account, date, and status**

```
proc sort data=have;
    by account my_date status;
run;
```

This will guarantee that your data is in the order that you need. Since we are looking only for year+1 after the status = 'na', anything that happens in-between that doesn't matter.

**Step 2: Use a data step to remember the first year when `na` happens for that account**

```
data want;
    set have;
    by account my_date status;

    retain first_na_year first_na_account;

    if(first.account) then call missing(first_na_year,first_na_account);

    if(status IN('na', 'tna') ) then do;
         first_na_year    = year;
         first_na_month   = month;
         first_na_account = account;
    end;

    if(    year           = first_na_year+1 
       AND first_na_month = month 
       AND account        = first_na_account)  
       AND status NOT IN('na', 'tna') )
    then do;
        new_status  = status ;
        new_my_date = my_date;
        new_money   = money;
    end;

    if(cmiss(new_status, new_my_date, new_money) ) = 0;

    drop first:;
run;
```

For each row, we compare three things:

1. Is the status not 'na'?
2. Is the year 1 year bigger than the last time it was 'na'?
3. Is this the same account we're comparing?

If all are true, then we want to create the three new variables.

**What's happening:**

SAS is inherently a looping language, so we do not need to use a `do` loop here. When SAS goes to a new row, it will clear all variables in the Program Data Vector (PDV) in preparation for filling them in with the new values in the row.

Since SAS the SAS data step only goes forwards and doesn't like to go backwards, we want it to remember the first time that `na` occurs for that account. `retain` tells SAS not to discard the value of a variable when it reads a new row.

When we are done doing our comparison and we've moved onto the next account, we reset these variables to missing. `by` group processing allows SAS to know exactly where the first and last occurrence of the account is in the dataset.

At the end, we output only if all 3 of the new variables are not missing. `cmiss` counts how many variables are not missing. Note that `output` is always implied before the `run` statement, so we simply need to use an "if without then" in this case.

The final statement, `drop first:;`, is a simple shortcut to remove any variables that start with the phrase `first`. This prevents them from being shown in the final dataset.

Comment: thanks a lot, however: I want to look after 12 month independent of the status in 12 month and I recognized I have two status "na" and " tna". So I changed a little bit your code: **  if(status = 'na' OR 'tna') then do;
         first_na_year = my_date;** and  ** if( year = first_na_year+100 AND account = first_na_account) then do;** But I get an error ( 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=,
              <>, =, >, ><, >=, AND, EQ, GE, GT, IN, LE, LT, MAX, MIN, NE, NG, NL, NOTIN, OR, ^=,
              |, ||, ~=.
)

Comment: thanks a lot really +1, If I apply your code I get a table where the new date is as the same. In the mean time I learned that I can apply sql code within sas. I wrote a code to join the table with itself and I solved it in this way. Any way thanks a lot for your hints and nice explanation I learned  a lot from your answer.